# How to make codes reusable in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I create reusable "functions" like this:

```
const Customer = (name, ID) => {
<Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{name}</Text>
<Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>{ID}</Text>}
```

So that I can insert customers into the following function easily.

```
function Shop() {
return (
    <DraxProvider>

        <DraxView>
            <Customer name="A" ID="1">
        </DraxView>

        <DraxView>
            <Customer name="B" ID="2">
        </DraxView>

        <DraxView>
            <Customer name="C" ID="3">
        </DraxView>

    </DraxProvider>
)}
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to make your `Customer` as a component like below

```js
const Customer = ({name, ID}) => (
<>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{name}</Text>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>{ID}</Text>
</>
)
```

Note the following:

- after the arrow sign you should use `(` sign as opposed to `{`
- Usage of `props` to pass parameter to component
- Usage of `<></>` aka `Fragments` since you have two `Text` component

With that you should be able to reuse as you intended

```js
function Shop() {
return (
    <DraxProvider>

        <DraxView>
            <Customer name="A" ID="1">
        </DraxView>

        <DraxView>
            <Customer name="B" ID="2">
        </DraxView>

        <DraxView>
            <Customer name="C" ID="3">
        </DraxView>

    </DraxProvider>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! No words can express my gratitude. Sorry that I'm not allowed to vote up your answer but will do so as soon as I upgrade.